# Tikz: several labels with same width at a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to attach several labels with annotations to a (**square**) node (the node has the text "32" here).

However, the labels (they have `draw`) should lie seamlessly together and should all have the ***same width** as the node (with 32)*.

How do I achieve a suitable font size for the labels?
(The label texts should all have the same font size.)

Or what is the best way to do this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily, very thin,
NumStyle/.style={minimum size=4mm, inner sep=0pt, draw},
LabelStyle/.style={minimum width=4mm, draw, font=\sffamily\tiny, inner xsep=0.5pt, inner ysep=1pt},
]

\node[NumStyle, fill=red, text=white,
label={[LabelStyle, 
scale=0.7%   try ?
]below:{1. Place}},
label={[LabelStyle, fill=yellow, name=P]above:{even (1/9)}},
label={[LabelStyle, fill=purple, yshift=2.7mm]{high (3/9)}},
]{32};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See the tikz manual, part about shapes. There is one rectangle which you can split into many parts. This is the geometry I read from your question.

Comment: @MS-SPO Ah, you mean the shape 'rectangle split'. Which offers multiple own options. I didn't even know that shape. Very good idea, I should be able to do something with that.

Comment: Right. Couldn‘t recall the name. Feel free to present an answer if it works the way you like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

- neglecting font
- using the `part fill` as list option
- the manual has more examples using `nodes` directly
- making the boxes wider is easy via textwidth

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4,draw,
           rectangle split part fill=
           {red!80!blue,yellow,red,white}]
    {
        high (3/9)
        \nodepart{two} 
            even (1/9)
        \nodepart{three}
            \textbf{\textcolor{white}{\LARGE{32}}}
        \nodepart{four}
            1. Place
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx! I posted a following-up question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/684495/46023

Answer (score 0):

Here's an other way to do it:

- define minimum width, height (for rectangles) and size for square
- place with absolute coordinates, doing some math by hand/head
- could be automized by using the `calc` library etc.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    [rc/.style={draw,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm},
     sq/.style={draw,minimum size=2cm}]
     
     \node [rc,fill=red!80!blue]    at (0,0) {high (3/9)};
     \node [rc,fill=yellow]         at (0,-1) {even (1/9)};
     \node [sq,fill=red]            at (0,-2.5) {\textbf{\textcolor{white}{\LARGE{32}}}};
     \node [rc]                     at (0,-4) {1. Place};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx, but the the parts 'should all have the same width '. So 'rectangle split' is the more elegant way.

Comment: I think, that‘s easy to solve: just adjust minimum size=3cm in the answer, and shift the last node a little.